# L297 + L298 circuit not working

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, h-bridge

I have paired up L297 and L298 together to make a bipolar stepper driver. 
My schematics are :
[image]

I have hooked up the step and direction pin  number 4 and 5  respectively on Arduino.
I am using a 5V power supply from a DC adaptor

The code I'm using is:

```
#define stepPin 4
#define dirPin 5

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Starting stepper exerciser.");

    pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
}

void loop() {
    int i, j;

    for (i=1000; i>=200; i-=100) {
        Serial.print("Speed: ");
        Serial.println(i);

        for (j=0; j<2000; j++) {
            digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
            delayMicroseconds(i);
            digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
            delayMicroseconds(i);
        }
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(dirPin, !digitalRead(dirPin));

        for (j=0; j<2000; j++) {
          digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
          delayMicroseconds(i);
          digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
          delayMicroseconds(i);
        }
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("Switching directions."); 
        digitalWrite(dirPin, !digitalRead(dirPin));
    }
}
```

I am using NEMA17 bipolar 5V motors , the data sheet can be found here :
[datasheet](http://www.eminebea.com/en/product/rotary/steppingmotor/hybrid/standard/data/17pm-j.pdf)

Motor specs are [here](http://www.eminebea.com/en/product/rotary/steppingmotor/hybrid/standard/)

I have also tried L297 with L293d , but the things aren't working the way they should.

Most probably the issues are with the oscillator or the clock pin (may be the pulse is not generating ), before posting the question , I had a quick google search which showed me I was not the only onne facing this issue.

Comment: What is the power source for the motors? Is the current capacity enough? What is the current limit you have set for each coil?

Comment: Power source is 5V (already mentioned in question ) , I have used 22k resistors for current sense pins , I'm only a novice and made the circuit following a schematic on  web , now it seems current sense pins determines the amount of current that can go into L298 . Also I tried vaarious combinations of resistor still no luck

Comment: 22K is too large, you barely drive the motors with a few mA. `Power source is 5V (already mentioned in question )` yes but you didn't specify if this was only for L297 and your schematic shows 36v supply for L298 so I can't make assumptions. So you drive L297/L298 with the same 5v that you use for the Arduino, what is the max current it can provide? Also what is the Vref applied in pin #15 of L297?

Comment: I see where are you getting , you want to say may be the power supply is not enough to run the motors , the dc adaptor is  rated at 5V , 1A , but earlier when I was using a L293D (arduino coupled to h-bridge and using AcclStepper ) , I was using the same power supply and motors were running at their best. I think that's why  we use L293D  (voltage and current amplification ), so no point of questioning the power supply. Isn't it ?

Comment: Surely one of the problems you have is the 22K sense resistors(RS, RS2). Depending on the current you want to use for the motor coils the supply current may or may not be enough. You can run them fine if you choose sense resistors for say 300mA/coil but not if you choose to drive the motor with 1A/coil or so. Also the datasheet lists several motors, what are the current specs for your specific one? You also didn't specify what is the Vref applied in pin #15 of L297. The actual schematic you have used would be helpful because currently the one you show is the generic one of the datasheet.

Comment: Actually my motor model is  17PM J311 P1ST , which is not available there

Comment: I haven't used a tripot to pin #15 , the VREF pin , I have pulled it up to Vcc , I have forgot the schematics , I just changed them ,by the way these are the schematics for L293d and L297  http://static.rcgroups.net/forums/attachments/3/1/2/5/2/2/a3229043-39-_schematics.jpg

Comment: `VREF pin is pulled up to Vcc.` In that case the winding current is limited to 5v/22000 = 0.23 mA

Comment: hmm , @alexan_e  , can you provide a better schematic please  , do I need to add a tripot ? To what voltage vref should be connected to ? should I change my power source too ?  What about using a 9volts battery ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the schematic, after all it is the reference design of the chip manufacturer. You need to find a tutorial about motor driving rather than doing random things in order to make it work.  Tutorials like [this](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/step/). A 9v battery is not sufficient to provide the motor current for more than a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, and change pin number to your like.
if this code work, likely the problem is in the delayMicroseconds number, some Stepper motor only work on higher than 300 and some on more higher number. 
when delayMicroseconds number too low, it will stall and sometime only humming.

when powerup, motor will spin clockwise, and if you push button, it's will delay 1 second, and start spin counterclockwise.

```
int val = 0; // push value from buttons pin
int jalan = 0;//moving status
int ditekan = 0;//push status
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT); //Enable
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT); //Step
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT); //Direction
  pinMode(4, INPUT); //push button

  digitalWrite(12,LOW);

}

void loop() 
{
  val = digitalRead(4);// read the push button value
  if(val == HIGH){
    ditekan = 1-ditekan;
    delay(1000);
  }
jalan = val;
if(ditekan == HIGH) {

    digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    } else {
    digitalWrite(10,LOW);
    digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    digitalWrite(11,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    }
    //delay(1);
}
```